# timeout exception in calling cplex with pyomo

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I am using cplex with pyomo to solve a mip. I put a time limit on the solver.
The problem is that sometimes (randomly) for some instances of the problem, I get timeout exception

> command ['/../cplex']" timed out after 90 second.

This 90 second is the time limit that I put on thesolver. However, those instances can be solved in a few seconds in re-runs.
Moreover, everything is ok when I use docplex to call cplex. The issue is with the way pyomo calls cplex. So, I do not understand why I get this random exception.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the reruns producing the same model? Cplex is deterministic (to a large extend), so the same model should behave the same.